# How to use SharedPreferences to store int that is incremented everytime the user clicks a button & retrieve value next time the app is launched

Tags: android

Im a beginner to Android Dev, and Ive been working on a pretty straightforward voting app for school.

Basically I've created objects in multiple activities that act as int counters to record votes(in form of clicks) for various posts. I have achieved this and also am able to view results for all the counters in a different activity. Also, the activity shifts to a new activity for the next position in the voting system automatically.

I realised that I would lose all the data/votes from the objects(counters) if the app was killed or crashed. Therefore, i tried implementing shared preferences to store and update the count of votes when the button was clicked.

However, my app crashes when I use the code to reassign a shared preference variable as the counter objects value.

I cannot seem to understand what and where to fix my code so that the counter resumes from last value. Below is my code:

```
public class SPL extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences retrieve = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Result", MODE_PRIVATE);

public int spl1count = retrieve.getInt("HB1", 0);
public int spl2count = retrieve.getInt("HB2", 0);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spl);

    final Button spl1vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spl1vb);
    final Button spl2vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spl2vb);


    spl1vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spl1count ++;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putInt("HB1", spl1count);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ASPL.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    spl2vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spl2count ++;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putInt("HB2", spl2count);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ASPL.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

The app crashes and after looking at the log it tells me there is an error on the line where I used a shared preference 'retrieved' to get back old data to fit into the counter.

If i remove this, the counter sets back to 0 when it is launched again, which i believe is because the counter isn't actually being set to a shared preference value.

Here is the code by which I am collecting results from shared preference in another activity:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final int spl1r = sharedPref.getInt("HB1", 0);
    final int spl2r = sharedPref.getInt("HB2", 0);
```

Then I use an alert dialog box to display spl1r and spl2r.

I've spent hours on the internet searching for a solution but none have worked for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

---

So I updated the code based on Evin's answer, but my code still crashes, this time in the `OnCreate`

Here is my new code:

```
     public class SPL extends AppCompatActivity {


SharedPreferences retrieve;
public int spl1count;
public int spl2count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    retrieve = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Result", MODE_PRIVATE);
    spl1count = retrieve.getInt("HB1", 0);
    spl2count = retrieve.getInt("HB2", 0);

     Button spl1vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spl1vb);
     Button spl2vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spl2vb);



    spl1vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spl1count ++;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putInt("HB1", spl1count);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ASPL.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    spl2vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spl2count ++;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Result", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putInt("HB2", spl2count);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ASPL.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

Am I still doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these lines inside the `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences retrieve = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Result", MODE_PRIVATE);

public int spl1count = retrieve.getInt("HB1", 0);
public int spl2count = retrieve.getInt("HB2", 0);
```

You are initializing them when they have no reference to any Android context yet (which is built in the `onCreate` method of the Activity/Application) that's why the getSharedPreferences method of the ApplicationContext will be a null reference.

---

If you still want to declare these values as member variables, your class would look something like (splitting the declaration and assignment):

```
public class SPL extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences retrieve;
    public int spl1count;
    public int spl2count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spl);

        retrieve = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Result", MODE_PRIVATE);
        spl1count = retrieve.getInt("HB1", 0);
        spl2count = retrieve.getInt("HB2", 0);

        final Button spl1vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        final Button spl2vb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

       /* Your listeners */
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean I should add that to the OnCreate of the activity which I'm retrieving into for the results alert box or into the one where I have the counters?

Comment: The one in which you are declaring those objects, I edited my question, kindly give it a check.

Comment: Yup I added it the way you told me to, but the app still crashes and gives me an error in the OnCreate now...

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace please?

Comment: I've added my updated code according to your answer, please have a look.

Comment: Yea but, I would need the stack trace (the red error that is shown in your logcat) :D

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.vaels.vaelsvotesample.SPL.onCreate(SPL.java:31)` @Evin1_

Comment: Change activity_main for activity_spl in the setContentView line. I updated my code. It should be `setContentView(R.layout.activity_spl);`

Comment: Omg it works now thank you soo much, you've been a lifesaver. Thanks so much :D